# Firebase function expected Promise or value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a cloud function on Firebase that uses a realtime database trigger. It fires `onWrite` and then I need to execute a series of commands using `Promises`.

The code executes when I use one promise and becomes unreliable when I chain promises. However, I always get this in the log:

`Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value`

I am returning values wherever required and yet I ended up with this message. My code is given below:

```
exports.sendQuotationToCustomer = functions.database.ref('/company/{companyId}/quotations/{quotationId}').onWrite((event) => {
  const companyId = event.params.companyId;
  console.log('Direct Generate');
  const root = event.data.ref.root;
  return root.child(`company/${companyId}/profile`).once('value')
  .then((profileSnap) => {
    console.log('1/Step');
    const profile = profileSnap.val();
    const docDefinition = helpers.createDocumentDefinition(profile, quotationData);
    return docDefinition;
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('2/Step');
    // Perform some manipulation over result. But meanwhile:
    return result;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Failed with error info: ${err}`);
  });
});
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: What exactly is `docDefinition`?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, docDefinition is for pdf generation that I plan to use at step 2 once this works. I've written a sample code here: `https://pastebin.com/Ubf10xqK`

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say it "becomes unreliable" when you chain promises? Are you doing any async work in step 2?

Comment: For the above code, it executes properly but I still get the above mentioned error message in the console. But yes, when i add some async code in step 2, it doesn't work. So am trying to sort the first issue of the error message.

Comment: Any indication in the console where this "error" is occuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you need to return an error in the catch to avoid the warning:

```
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(`Failed with error info: ${err}`);
  return err;
});
```

This could also happen if `docDefinition` were `undefined`. It might be a good idea to check for that and throw an error in that case.